# Adding RadioButtons from inflated listview layout into RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview (which gets inflated with a layout) and a custom adapter extending BaseAdapter.  Each row of the listview contains a radiobutton, a textview and an imageview.

My problem is I can't add all the radiobuttons into a RadioGroup.  I want to control the radiobuttons so that only one can be selected at any time.

Can someone help please?

My layout of listview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_activity_object_setup_final_objects"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

My XML used to inflate:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rbn_activity_object_setup_final_list_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="" android:button="@drawable/radio_button"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_activity_object_setup_final_list_layout_div_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rbn_activity_object_setup_final_list_layout"
    android:src="@drawable/table_divider_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txv_activity_object_setup_final_list_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_activity_object_setup_final_list_layout_div_vertical"
    android:text="Object"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_activity_object_setup_final_list_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/object_icon_keys" />
```

My code for custom adapter:

```
    class ObjectAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<ObjectType> objectTypeData;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ObjectAdapter(Context context, List<ObjectType> objectTypeList) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.objectTypeData = objectTypeList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objectTypeData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objectTypeData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewGroup vg;

        if (convertView != null) {
            vg = (ViewGroup) convertView;
        } else {
            vg = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_object_setup_final_list_layout, null);
        }

        ObjectType objectType = objectTypeData.get(position);

        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) vg.findViewById(R.id.rbn_activity_object_setup_final_list_layout);
        radioButton.setButtonDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radio_button));
        if (objectType.getRadioButtonImage() == strDisabled) {
            radioButton.setEnabled(false);
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
        }
        else if (objectType.getRadioButtonImage() == strChecked) {
            radioButton.setEnabled(true);
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            radioButton.setEnabled(true);
            radioButton.setChecked(false);
        }

        TextView objectName = (TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.txv_activity_object_setup_final_list_layout);
        objectName.setText(objectType.getTitle());

        ImageView objectImage = (ImageView) vg.findViewById(R.id.img_activity_object_setup_final_list_layout);
        if (objectType.getObjectTypeImage() == getString(R.string.strKeys)) {
            objectImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.object_icon_keys));
        }
        else if (objectType.getObjectTypeImage() == getString(R.string.strWallet)) {
            objectImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.object_icon_wallet));
        }
        else if (objectType.getObjectTypeImage() == getString(R.string.strBag)) {
            objectImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.object_icon_bag));
        }
        else if (objectType.getObjectTypeImage() == getString(R.string.strLaptop)) {
            objectImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.object_icon_laptop));
        }
        else {
            objectImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.object_icon_default));
        }

        return vg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need RadioGroup? Have You tried to control single check from Your adapter? What data is contained in ObjectType?

Comment: Oh, I wanted to have the control automated so that I don't have to code the checking.  ObjectType is he modaldata layer that contains 3 items:
 public String radioButtonImage;
 public String title;
 public String objectTypeImage;

Any leads on how to code it in the adapter?

Comment: You can try to track currently checked (e.g. its index) item and update it when another item get selected. In adapter You'll need to check if position == checkedIndex and set item state accordingly.

Comment: Thanks!  I have done it as per below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the radiobuttons to an OnClickListener.
2. In the OnClick event, save the selectedItem index.
3. Call the notifyDataSetChanged method of the adapter.
4. In the adapter, check if the selectedItem==position to decide if the radiobutton should be checked or not.

`radioButton.setChecked(selectionIndex==position);`